# Is it okay to mutate data in a loop in clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I'm super new to Clojure, and I'm going through Project Euler challenges to get a feel for the language.  I'm on [this one](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5), and I want to solve it by using a map to map factors to number of max number of occurrences in all the numbers, so to do this in an imperative language, I would simply update the map in each iteration of the loop.

I'm tempted to do this same sort of thing in Clojure: create a map, and then update it (or rather retrieve it, add the new value, and save it in the old map's place, since data is immutable) for each number from 1-20, and then use the final map to compute the answer.

This feels wrong though, as if I'm not thinking functionally.  Am I missing something, or is there some kind of mapping between how things would normally be done imperatively, and what functional constructs I could use to do the same sort of thing?

Thanks!

Comment: The question is: given all the prime factors in the numbers between 2 and N inclusive, how many times must each factor appear in a collection such that the multiplication of all instances together is divisible by all numbers in the range? This collection can be constructed using functions, no loops needed. Hint: look at functions such as `group-by` or `frequencies`.

Comment: Think in terms of recursion and expressions returning values rather than statements that do some stuff on some place. Even a single expression that doesn't return anything is something that is pulling you to imperative thinking.

Answer (score 3):

**the first rule of the clojure club: you never mutate anything in the clojure club!**

seriousely, do not mutate anything, unless it is inevitable (like keeping the global state of the application). To keep the loop state, you usually just pass it as one of the loop parameters. Speaking of your task, for example here is an example of `factors` function:

```
(defn factors [n]
  (loop [n n d 2 f []]
    (cond (== 1 n) f
          (zero? (rem n d)) (recur (/ n d) d (conj f d))
          :else (recur n (inc d) f))))
```

so, you just "accumulate" factors in `f`, and pass it to the next iteration.

and for the rest of the task you should use higher order functions:

```
(->> (range 2 20)
     (map (comp frequencies factors))
     (apply merge-with max)
     (reduce-kv #(apply * %1 (repeat %3 %2)) 1))
```

`(map (comp frequencies factors))` creates the sequence of maps, where each map is a *prime factor* to *power of this factor in the number*, for each number in range:

```
({2 1} {3 1}           ; 2 3
 {2 2} {5 1}           ; 4 5
 {2 1, 3 1} {7 1}      ; 6 7
 {2 3} {3 2}           ; 8 9
 {2 1, 5 1} {11 1}     ; 10 11
 {2 2, 3 1} {13 1}     ; 12 13
 {2 1, 7 1} {3 1, 5 1} ; 14 15
 {2 4} {17 1}          ; 16 17
 {2 1, 3 2} {19 1})    ; 18 19
```

`(apply merge-with max)` merges these maps, using the maximum of two values if the keys are equal

```
{2 4, 3 2, 5 1, 7 1, 11 1, 13 1, 17 1, 19 1}
```

then you just multiply `k ^ val`

by the way, this task has a better solution which can be fulfilled with paper and pencil, or one line of code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm totally agree with **leetwinski** - you should never mutate variables in Clojure (unless there is no other way to do the job).

The only thing I want to add to [**leetwinski**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33262345/1202461) is a more elegant solution:

```clj
(defn multiple [numbers]
  (reduce #(let [n (/ %1 %2)]
            ; try to divide accumulator by the next number in input collection
            (if (ratio? n)
                ; multiply accumulator by resulting denominator
                (* %1 (denominator n))
                ; or leave it unchanged if it already evenly divisible
                %1))
          numbers))
```

```clj
(multiple (range 1N 11)) ; => 2520N
(multiple (range 1N 21)) ; => 232792560N
```

Comment: right you are, i just wanted to illustrate a common way to use loop/recur, as the question was about loops. There are loads of solutions that are better than mine. Yours is just mind blowing!

Comment: like this one: `(reduce #(apply * %1 (repeat (short (/ (Math/log 20) (Math/log %2))) %2)) 1 [2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19])` which is nice and fast solution if you have pre-cached list ot primes less than `n`

Answer (score 1):

A Clojure `loop` is just a `let` that doubles as a point of *tail recursion*: where, roughly speaking, the `loop` form evaluates to the recursive call as such, without doing anything to it. `recur` invokes  tail recursion to the enclosing `loop`, and performs it by a *goto* instead of using the call stack.

Should you mutate loop data? The question doesn't arise. You can't! You can no more mutate `loop` bindings than `let` bindings. `recur` re-enters the loop with renewed bindings.

`loop` is idiomatic Clojure, and is the simplest way to solve many problems. However, as you can see from the other answers, the sequence library (`map`, `filter`, `reduce` ...) encapsulates many common data/control patterns, which often express a solution more clearly and concisely.